# Blank page on each HTTP request in Angular 4

Tags: angular

The issue is the blank screen I am facing on each request. Then after my data pages are open. I want to remove this screen got no solution. please help with this.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: "/login",
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: MainLayoutComponent,
        children: [

            { path: 'add-department', component: DepartmentComponent },
            { path: 'department-list', component: DepartmentListComponent },
            { path: 'edit-department', component: EditDepartmentComponent },
            { path: 'add-user-role', component: UserRoleComponent },
            { path: 'user-role', component: UserRoleMenuComponent },
            { path: 'user-role-list', component: UserRoleListComponent },
            { path: 'edit-user-role', component: EditUserRoleComponent },
            { path: 'edit-user-role-menu', component: EditUserRoleMenuComponent },
            { path: 'add-user', component: AddUserComponent },
            { path: 'user-list', component: AdminUserListComponent },
            { path: 'edit-user', component: EditUserComponent },
            { path: 'student-list', component: StudentUserListComponent },
            { path: 'add-student', component: AddStudentComponent }
        ]
    },   
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent },
    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }  
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Comment: Do you mean to add a *loader/ progress bar*?

Comment: I have already added a loader but I don't need it.

Comment: Then what do you mean by blank screen? If possible then provide stackblitz examples where *I/we* can reproduce the issue

Comment: Can you be more explicit? Maybe you can add a screenshot? What behavior do you want to achieve?

Comment: for more details of blank page issue of mine please check video url - https://youtu.be/-U_8L5tNkDU

Comment: Please answer i am waiting